# Qt QNetworkReply downloadProgress bytesTotal = -1

Tags: php, qt, download

```
void QNetworkReply::downloadProgress(qint64 bytesReceived, qint64 bytesTotal) [signal]

// The bytesReceived parameter indicates the number of bytes received, while bytesTotal indicates the total number of bytes expected to be downloaded. If the number of bytes to be downloaded is not known, bytesTotal will be -1.
```

I receive bytesTotal = -1 every time. I tried `header('Content-Length: '.strlen($content));` in my php file, but no result. 
What php header or something else can help?

Answer (score 0):

The solution header is:

```
header("Content-type: application/octet-stream");
header("Content-length: ".strlen($content));
```